High CPU temps while gaming and low CPU temps while stress testing
I can't figure out why my CPU temps while gaming and while stress testing are so different
CPU temps:
idle - 40-50 C
while gaming - 85-95 C (CPU usage 15%-30%)
AIDA64 CPU stress test - ~60 C (CPU usage 100%)
i also tried running Furmark GPU test and AIDA64 CPU stress test at the same time to see if it's related, but CPU temp is still around 60 C
Setup:
CPU: R9 7900x with lian li galahad aio 360
GPU: RTX 3080TI
MB: Asus TUF Gaming X670E-Plus WiFi
Chassis: Lian Li with a lot of fans

Please find Which computer science / programming Stack Exchange sites do I post on?
